# How to return a blob file from spring boot rest API?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, blob

I have a data base table where the files have been stored as a BLOB. Now, I need to have a spring boot java API which will download the file and return to front end of the application (node js). Please help me to get this done.

note : the file format can be anything (txt, pdf , xls and etc ).

any kind of help or suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/70444557/7726319

Comment: @Vedha Not sure it is possible. You can return either a byte[] or Base64 that will be rendered as PDF directly from the browser.
In case of byte[] you simply add it to the content of the response, in case of Base64 you need to decode it.

Comment: @GiacomoBartoli - Thanks. I have tried to return it as byte[] and it's working fine.